# Condition for setting up a vagrant synced folder

Tags: directory, vagrant, typo3, conditional-statements, shared

I want to setup a synced folder in vagrant, but only if the mountpoint already exists in the guest machine.

This is my synced folder:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "./typo3conf", "/var/www/typo3conf",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]
```

Now before this synced_folder is setup, I would like to check, if the directory /var/www/typo3conf already exists and ONLY THEN sync this folder to the host.

Background: Typo3 will create the folder during inital setup, but will not execute the setup, if the folder already exists. As soon as it is created by the setup process, it should also be synced to the host.

Comment: The easiest would be to use a provisioning tool (e.g. chef) to make sure the folder exists.

Comment: But can I create a shared folder from Chef? Chef is running inside the guest, the shared folder config is on the host....Thanks!

Comment: I see, that might be a problem. We use TYPO3 within vagrant boxes and just mount the whole root folder of a TYPO3 installation in /var/www. The chef recipes make sure the right subfolders exist